# How to replace a tag with a space in a text file?

Tags: java

```
<ul class="uinfo2"><li class="uname2">ruo</li>
<ul class="uinfo2"><li class="uname"><b>Oinsen</b></li>
```

If the file contains the above HTML lines, I want to replace the bold tag from the entire source code.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking here. Can you give further detail on what you mean by *"I want to replace the bold tag from the entire source code"*? (Click the "edit" link under your post to update it with more information.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove any `<b>` tags from your HTML? If so, you can use jQuery:

```
$('b').contents().unwrap();
```

See: [Remove a HTML tag but keep the innerHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232961/jquery-remove-a-tag-but-keep-innerhtml)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm not sure jQuery's involved here? The OP tagged it [Java] (although it could very well be incorrectly tagged).

Comment: True. I guess I assumed too Javascript was what the OP wanted before thinking about it.

Comment: Don't worry, though. [There's always room for a jQuery answer!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)

Answer (score 1):

read all content of file and store in a String (for example String content;) using replaceAll method.
line.replaceAll("<b>", " ").replaceAll("</b>"," ");
And finally write new String into that file.

```
    File file = new File("input.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(line.replaceAll("<b>", " ").replaceAll("</b>", " "));         

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    writer.write(sb.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

here is the code.

Comment: This assumes that he means that he wants to remove the bolding tags but not the enclosed content -- "0insen" in the example. 'Not saying that isn't what he means, just pointing out the ambiguity in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) can accomplish this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import nu.xom.ParsingException;
import nu.xom.ValidityException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class HtmlTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws SAXException, ValidityException, ParsingException, IOException {
        String[] tagsToKeep = new String[] {"ul", "li"};
        String html = "<ul class=\"uinfo2\"><li class=\"uname2\">ruo</li>\n<ul class=\"uinfo2\"><li class=\"uname\"><b>Oinsen</b></li>";
        System.out.println(JSoup.clean(html, Whitelist.none().addTags(tagsToKeep)));
    }
}
```

Initialize `tagsToKeep` with all of the tags you do not want removed and pass it to `addTags`.

Comment: doesn't it do exactly the opposite?

Comment: Yeah I just realized that and am addressing it :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regular Expressions, but they quickly become complicated when trying to match HTML.  If your file in XHTML compliant (which this appears to be), I'd recommend loading the file as XML and using XPath to determine if this meets your criteria - and then DOM operations to replace the bold tag however you require.

Comment: (This assumes you're doing this in Java, and not JavaScript - as another answer is assuming...)

Comment: ziesemer - The question is tagged as being Java by the original author, so I don't think a JavaScript solution is required.