# How to remove an element but not the content inside it?

Tags: jquery

How can I remove an element but not the content **inside** that element?

```
<a href="#">
    <span>
        <img src="pic-1.jpg"/>
    </span>
</a>
```

I want to **remove** the `span` that wraps the image.

So I can get,

```
<a href="#">

    <img src="pic-1.jpg"/>

</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a HTML tag but keep the innerHtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232961/remove-a-html-tag-but-keep-the-innerhtml)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need [unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
$('img').unwrap();
```

Comment: Ooh, nice function. +1 for actually searching instead of doing what I did.

Comment: I know this is Q&A is old, but what about unwrapping text? It's possible to unwrap an element but how about plain text?

Comment: @dfsq So simple and yet so clever. :)

Answer (score 10):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $span = $('span');
  $span.replaceWith($span.html());
});
```

see example http://jsfiddle.net/vikastyagi87/Xaa39/6/

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer because it also works for unwrapping text (not only DOM elements)

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery function `unwrap()` is what you're looking for:

> Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

Check out [the API doc page](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to modify your HTML architecture a bit here:

```
<a href="#" id="my_href">
    <span id="my_span">
        <img src="pic-1.jpg"/>
    </span>
</a>
```

**jQuery solution:**

```
$("#my_href").html($("#my_span").html());
```

**Non jQuery solution:**

```
document.getElementById("my_href").innerHTML = document.getElementById("my_span").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Using HTML like this is generally a bad practice. You're destroying and recreating nodes instead of simply relocating the ones to keep, and removing the ones to discard. It'll also destroy any handlers or other data associated with the `img` element.

Comment: Ah, really? Okay, I'll avoid that in the future then. :)

Comment: That is **NOT** jQuery solution!

Comment: @gdoron Could you be a little more explicit please? Thanks.

Comment: All was said by @amnotiam. Just use `unwrap` Now that's a jQuery solution! **simple-clean-effective => jQuery solution.**

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Yeah, I'd actually never heard of `unwrap`. I just rolled my own solution.