# How to remove all href from an AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, response, href, removeall

I'm importing an HTML file and I want to remove all `href` from all elements on it, so the final text doesn't link anywhere and appears like "normal" text.

I'm already taking just a part `div#divvy` from this HTML, so the process of removing `href` must works on it and not on all the response.

The final result should go to `div#pepeland`.

I have this code:

```
function pepe(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.site.com/text.html',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response){
            $('#pepeland').html(jQuery(response).find('#divvy').html());
        }
    });
};
```

I think but am not sure that maybe I should insert something like one of these following lines inside the above code, but I don't know how to do it.

```
$(response).querySelectorAll("href").remove();
```

or

```
$(response).attr('href', '');
```

or

```
response.replace("href", '');
```

---

on below answers, i realize that what i want is to remove all the  tag without removing the text. Because the words keeps formatted with underline and all the attributes of the  tag. So roasted wrote my the right answer for this, see below!

Comment: your `response` isn't technically available like that.  You have to basically append the HTML that comes from your post, then write a line under that post to find the specific links within that appended html

Comment: His response is available like that. When you wrap the returned data as a jQuery object `$(data)`, you can now use jQuery methods and selectors on it, so `$(response).find('[href]').prop('href', '');` will look for any element within the response that has an href property, then will take that property and change it to be nothing.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thank you, I stand corrected.  How about just `.removeAttr()`?

Comment: You should not mention the right answer from within your body text, that's what upvotes and more precisely for your "accepted answers" are for. AFAIK, you do not have the privilege of upvotes but accepted answers should be available for you. Please, use those. All in all, the last paragraph seems unnecessary. A question should be a question, an answer should be an answer, and each should stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see your html file to see how to select the elements but you would need to loop through all the elements to replace them all. So something like this...

```
$('YOUR SELECTOR').each(function(){
      $(this).contents().unwrap();
});
```

This will take the anchor tag away and make it purely text.

similar to the answer of this question.. [Remove a HTML tag but keep the innerHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232961/jquery-remove-a-tag-but-keep-innerhtml)

Comment: it should be `.contents()` not `.contents`

Comment: $(this) would refer to whatever your selector was to start the each function, without your HTML I can't really tell you what your selector should be... but it could be something like $('#pepeland a').each(function...etc.

Comment: perfect! i mixed this with roasted answer (below). Thanks!! :)

Comment: @sergius "answer below" is a misguiding concept, as answers can appear in different order due to upvotes. Hence, if you want to reference to another answer, please use its share-link. Also, thanks via comments are not needed, that's what upvotes are for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function pepe(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.site.com/text.html',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response){
            var $divvy = $(response).find('#divvy');
            $divvy.find('a').each(function(){$(this).replaceWith($(this).text())});
            $('#pepeland').html($divvy);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: oh, it works, thanks! but i realize that what i want is to remove all the <a></a> tag without removing the text. Because the words keeps formatted with underline and all the attributes of the <a> tag. Should i start a new question ?

Comment: See updated answer using remove(). Maybe you could use unwrap() if e.g there is img nested in some link tag (<a>)

Comment: oh, but the text inside <a></a> is also removed. How i can preserve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.site.com/text.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response){
        $('#pepeland').html(response);
        $('#pepeland a').removeAttr('href');
    }
});
```

This would remove the href attribute on all links inside your appended html

Comment: Have you tried what @ohGodWhy said in his post?  Then use `removeAttr()`?

Comment: yes, it partially works. See roasted comments, i modified my needs, sorry, it's my first time asking here.