# Stripping <script> tags but not <br>

Tags: jquery, html, strip

I try to make a simple chatroom, But how to I strip `<script>`'s tag from chat msg ?

**HTML :**

```
<div></div>
<textarea>Hello , <script>alert('world');</script>
This is a new line !
</textarea>
<button>Send</button>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var msg = $('textarea').val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />")
    $('div').append(msg);
});
```

When user click 'send', I want the result to be

> Hello , alert('world');
>
> This is a new line !

without `<script></script>` tags but with `<br>` tag instead of newline.

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/rGNEe/

Comment: As I remember there was a similar question some time ago:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232961/jquery-remove-a-tag-but-keep-innerhtml

Comment: I looked this topic too, but how to use with <textarea>'s value ? @eeree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/q5QhY/)

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var msg = $('textarea').val().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />")
    $('#res').append(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var msg = $('textarea').val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />").replace(/</, '&lt;').replace(/>/, '&gt;')
    $('div').append(msg);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aQ7Cr/)