# jQuery Hide part of a string based on text

Tags: jquery, hide, contains

If you have HTML like:

```
<div class="text">Good Stuff Hide Me</div>
<div class="text">Great Stuff Hide Me</div>
<div class="text">Best Stuff Hide Me</div>
```

and want to hide just "Hide Me" in every instance of div.text so you're left with

Good Stuff
Great Stuff
Best Stuff

How would you do that with jQuery?

This `$("div:contains('Hide Me')").hide();` hides the entire string.  How can you isolate the text you want to hide?

Comment: Hide Me would need to be enclosed in an element. The best jQuery could do the recreate the whole `.text` block and create a new element. You would be better off starting with `<span class="hide">Hide Me</span>`.

Comment: Remove the text or hide the text? There is a big difference and one I don't know if it can be cleanly done....

Comment: @useSticks hide is fine. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to actually remove the text, use:

```
$('div.text').text(function (i, t) {
    return t.replace(' Hide Me', '');
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/F7WVj/1)**

To hide it, use:

```
$('div.text').html(function (i, t) {
    return t.replace('Hide Me', '<span class="hidden">Hide Me</span>');
})
```

with the CSS `.hidden {
    display:none;
}`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gShM4/1)**

Comment: Perfect.  The only thing I want to add is that my example had a class name so it would be $('div.text') .  In my actual code I have the "Text to be hidden" text in other divs that I don't want to hide so just needed to specify the ones I wanted.  Little nitpick for a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, other than useSticks's, is to do what j08691 suggested but to then to use `$('.hidden').contents().unwrap()` (or the native alternative) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232961/jquery-remove-a-tag-but-keep-innerhtml). This way, you could dynamically tell it what you want to hide/unhide, perhaps based on what the user enters.

Answer (score -1):

j08691 has it, but if you are going to be switching it to a span to hide it, it implies that you want to bring it back. You would be wise to think of splitting the text into 2 tags yourself so that you can more cleanly search for it and handle bringing it back easier later.

```
 <div class="text">Good Stuff <span class="hideMe">Hide Me</span></div>
 <div class="text">Great Stuff <span class="hideMe">Hide Me</span></div>
 <div class="text">Best Stuff <span class="hideMe">Hide Me</span></div>
```

So you have

```
 $(".hideMe").hide()
 $(".hideMe").show()
```