# How to remove variable number of p tags from a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paragraph

I have a string that contains variable HTML content. The string can contain one, more or no p tags which may also have classes on them.

What is the best way to **remove all p tags** from this using jQuery while keeping the HTML content of each of them.

I first tried the following but of course this only works if I have the whole string wrapped in a paragraph and it would not cover if the paragraphs have classes or other attributes on them:

```
str.substring(3).slice(0, -4);
```

### Edit

Here is an example but the number of p tags can vary and there can also be none at all.

**Example before:**

```
<p>Some text <p class="someClass"> Some other text</p> Some more text</p>
```

**Example after:**

```
"Some text Some other text Some more text"
```

Comment: Can you post an example of a string with the content to be removed, and what you want it to be after removal?

Comment: Sure, will update my post.

Comment: You want the content to remain intact and to remove the `p` tags wrapping it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: What's generating this (invalid) HTML, you'd probably have better luck solving the problem, rather than treating the symptoms.

Comment: Found a smilar post. The solution works great!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232961/jquery-remove-a-tag-but-keep-innerhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to do this. It only removes the p-tags and leaves all other tags in place.

**JavaScript**

```
var string = "<p>this is a test with <p class='bold'>multiple</p> p-tags.</p><span>THIS IS COOL</span>";
var result = string.replace(/<[\/]{0,1}(p)[^><]*>/ig,"");

console.log(result);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8ab87yLw/1/)**

If you'd like to remove all tags, you could use `/(<([^>]+)>)/ig` instead as regex.

Comment: Thanks for this ! Usually I try to avoid Regex but I think in this case it makes sense and all the other suggestions didnt work for my case. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use  [**Unwrap**](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/): `$('p').contents().unwrap()`

It is the opposite of wrap in that it removes the parents of the selector. The `p` tags are the parent elements of the content, selecting the content before unwraping will unwrap the `p` tags. **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2m3cuuut/3/)**

Comment: Yes, but, given the HTML string in the question, I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work quite as you want it.

Comment: Thanks. So would Regex be the better approach here ?

Comment: Unwrap is the way to do it, however it's not as simple as in the provided example.

Comment: It will find all the p tags in the body and unwrap it. If you want to trigger it in a specific section then use HTML : `<article><p>Hello</p> <p>World</p></article>`, jQuery : `$('article p').contents().unwrap()`

Comment: Thanks, All ! @dfsq: Can you explain what you mean by it's not as simple ?

Comment: @user2571510 If you have a string like `'<p>one</p><span>span</span><p>two</p>'`, how would you use above example with it?

Comment: Ok but thats exactly what I have. :)

Comment: I know, that's why I said that this answer gives a hint, but not actually answers the question.

Comment: I added an addendum to my answer incase anyone else got caught up on the span thing as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var str = "<p>Test</p>";
var res = str.replace("<p>", "").replace("</p>", "");
```

Comment: Thanks - this wouldnt cover p tags with classes or style attributes on them.

Comment: Or more than one `<p>` and `</p>`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, and you want the p tags removed but the content still there it should be as simple as:

```
str.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '');
```

Comment: Thanks - this wouldnt cover p tags with classes or style attributes on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use replaceWith  - [**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2m3cuuut/2/), readable and works with parent / child tags

```
$('p').replaceWith($('p').text())
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! Would this also cover multiple p tags as well as p tags with classes or other attributes on them ?

Comment: And again, how would you use it with a string, not DOM nodes? You have `'<p>one</p><span>span</span><p>two</p>'` string, how would you remove all `p` from it?

Comment: @dfsq That isn't the HTML structure the questioner presented.