# Changing background color of <mark> tag in order to mimic CTRL+F functionality

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to mimic the functionality of CTRL+F of the browser within a specific div. First, the user will enter a search query, click 'find,' and all of the matching results will be highlighted within the div. I am using the following function (which is working exactly as it should) to achieve this:

```
function highlight(str, $elem) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str + "(?!([^<]+)?>)", "gi");
    var found = [];

    $elem.html($elem.html().replace(/<\/?mark>/g, ''));

    if (str === '') return found;

    $elem.html($elem.html().replace(regex, function (matched) {
        found.push(matched);
        return "<mark>" + matched + "</mark>";
    }));

    return found;
}
```

Once this function highlights all of the matched results, I am using the following conditional to scroll through the div and stop at each result:

```
if (found.length > 0) {
    $("#text").scrollTop($("mark:eq(" + searchIndex++ +")").offset().top - $("#text").offset().top + $("#text").scrollTop());
    if (searchIndex === found.length) searchIndex = 0;
}
```

This also works exactly as expected. Where I am running into trouble is trying to change the css background-color attribute of the currently "active" < mark > tag. I am trying to use something like the below to accomplish this, but it appears to be breaking the internet.

```
if (found.length > 0) {
    $("mark:eq(" + (searchIndex - 1 === -1) ? found.length-1 : searchIndex-1 +")").css({"background-color": "#FFFF00"}) ;
    $("mark:eq(" + searchIndex +")").css({"background-color": "#DAA520"}) ;
    $("#text").scrollTop($("mark:eq(" + searchIndex++ +")").offset().top - $("#text").offset().top + $("#text").scrollTop());
    if (searchIndex === found.length) searchIndex = 0;
}
```

For some reason this is inserting another < mark > tag surrounding the text within < h1 > and I have no idea why that would happen. The links to jsfiddle are below:

[Working search (without background-color changing)](https://jsfiddle.net/simonpaonessa/56nznmm7/2/)

[Non-working search (with background-color changing)](https://jsfiddle.net/simonpaonessa/6a4t8hgz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because you were calling function `highlight` each time you click the `find` button. It has to be called only at the first time.

```
var searchIndex = 0;
var first_click = true;
var found;

$("#findField").change(function () {
    searchIndex = 0;
    first_click = true;

    highlight('', $("#text"));  
});

$("#find").click(function () {
    if (first_click) {
        found = highlight(
          $("#findField").val().replace(/\s$/g, ''),
          $("#text")
        );

        first_click = false;
    }

    if (found.length > 0) {
        $("mark:eq(" + ((searchIndex - 1 === -1) ? found.length - 1 : searchIndex - 1) +")").css({"background-color": ""});

        $("#text").scrollTop($("mark:eq(" + searchIndex++ +")").offset().top - $("#text").offset().top + $("#text").scrollTop());

        $("mark:eq(" + ((searchIndex - 1 === -1) ? found.length - 1 : searchIndex - 1) +")").css({"background-color": "#DAA520"});

        if (searchIndex === found.length) searchIndex = 0;
    }
});

$("#findField").mouseup(function () {
    searchIndex = 0;
    this.select();
});

$("#clear").click(function () {
    searchIndex = 0;
    $("#findField").val('');
    highlight('', $("#text"));
});

function highlight(str, $elem) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str + "(?!([^<]+)?>)", "gi");
    var found = [];

    //$elem.html($elem.html().replace(/<\/?mark>/g, ''));

    $elem.find("mark").each(function () {
        $(this).contents().unwrap();
    });

    if (str === '') return found;

    $elem.html($elem.html().replace(regex, function (matched) {
        found.push(matched);
        return "<mark>" + matched + "</mark>";
    }));

    return found;
}
```

**EDITED**

So I added `change` function to the `#findField`, and also I changed this `$elem.html($elem.html().replace(/<\/?mark>/g, ''));` to:

```
$elem.find("mark").each(function () {
    $(this).contents().unwrap();
});
```

Because, that regular will not match browned found text (`<mark style="background-color: rgb(218, 165, 32);">`...

If you dont understand this `$(this).contents().unwrap();`, see it here:
[Remove a HTML tag but keep the innerHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232961/remove-a-html-tag-but-keep-the-innerhtml)

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6a4t8hgz/5/)

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something I was overlooking. Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes. Although, it appears as though your solution breaks clear function and the ability to search for a subsequent term. Probably still something to do with calling the highlight function.

Comment: It appears as though your solution breaks the clear function and the ability to search for a subsequent term. Probably still something to do with calling the highlight function.

Comment: Yes, I am doing it better. You just need to clear highlighted text when searched text is changed.

Comment: Yet again, something I overlooked. Completely forgot the fact that jQuery css changes occur inline. Thank you, sir. Accepting your answer and upvoting. :-)

Comment: @Legionar fiddle link makes 404

Comment: @Visruth looks like they are deleting fiddles after couple years :-(