# Strip all unwanted tags from html string but preserve whitespace in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to strip my html content of all unwanted tags and just return text with basic formatting (ul, b, u, p etc) or just plain text (but preserving new lines, spacing etc) however I am having trouble creating a catch all solution which will let me keep the structure of the content that I pasted.

Example string:

```
    <p class="Bodytext" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <span lang="EN-GB">Hello
            <span class="Apple-converted-space"> world,   </span>
            <span class="Cross-reference">
                <a href="" style="color: rgb(66, 139, 202);background-color: transparent;">Cough
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class="Apple-converted-space"></span>and
            <span class="Apple-converted-space"></span>
            <span class="Cross-reference">
                <a href="" style="color: rgb(66, 139, 202);background-color: transparent;">Feverish - risk assessment</a>
            </span>.
            <span class="Apple-converted-space"></span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p class="Bodytext" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <span lang="EN-GB">Fin.  </span>
    </p>
```

Comment: How about just getting `.textContent` of a node? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent  example: http://jsfiddle.net/gLrramna/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain JavaScript solution to remove all `span` elements from within HTML but leave their inner content:

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
while(span.length) {
    var parent = span[ 0 ].parentNode;
    while( span[ 0 ].firstChild ) {
        parent.insertBefore(  span[ 0 ].firstChild, span[ 0 ] );
    }
     parent.removeChild( span[ 0 ] );
}
```

You can also do this much more simply by using jQuery, as shown in this example which will remove the `span` tags, as well as `p`, `b`, `ul`, `li` tags, but leave their inner content:

```
$("span, p, b, ul, li").contents().unwrap();
```

See also: [Remove a HTML tag but keep the innerHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232961/remove-a-html-tag-but-keep-the-innerhtml)

It may also be beneficial to note that anytime you have two or more consecutive spaces, a modern browser will typically truncate these to one space when they display. If you want to preserve the spacing as multiple spaces, I would replace the regularly typed space "" characters with "`&nbsp;`" HTML encoded spaces. Ordinary JavaScript has a string replace method you can use for that, if desired.

EDIT: If you wish to remove all HTML tags from within a JavaScript string, try the following:

```
myString.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
```

See also: [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: hey i appreciate the response but this is not suitable answer, I only have a string, not the dom to work with so I can't just grab the elements and unwrap them. Also this sample html contains alot of spans yes but I am wishing to account for any type of element in my parser

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have been able to come up with is this...

`'Name<br /><a href="something">here.</a>'.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,' ').replace(/\s{2,}/gi, ' ').trim()`

I don't think it's the most elegant but it does seem to work pretty consistently.