# How to correctly take out text from an element and destroy the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4qafpgph/)

I've a paragraph tag with 2 (can be more) `highlight` tags inside it.

What I want to do now is, when I click the button, I want the `highlight` tag that contains 'removable' text to be destroyed and replace with plain text of 'removable' without the `highlight` tag and all data-* attributes.

**HTML**:

```
<p>
  <highlight class="highlight" data-id="1464586442243" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<p>first</p><button class=&quot;btn edit_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586442243&quot;>Edit</button>&amp;nbsp;<button class=&quot;btn delete_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586442243&quot;>Delete</button>"
  id="anchor_1464586442243" data-original-title="" title="">Section</highlight> 1
  <highlight class="highlight" data-id="1464586450092" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<p>second</p><button class=&quot;btn edit_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586450092&quot;>Edit</button>&amp;nbsp;<button class=&quot;btn delete_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586450092&quot;>Delete</button>"
  id="anchor_1464586450092" data-original-title="" title="">removable</highlight> true</p>
<button id="remove" type="button">Remove</button>
```

**JS**:

```
$(function() {
  $('#remove').click(function() {
    // i stuck here
  });
});
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**:

```
<p>
  <highlight class="highlight" data-id="1464586442243" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<p>first</p><button class=&quot;btn edit_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586442243&quot;>Edit</button>&amp;nbsp;<button class=&quot;btn delete_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586442243&quot;>Delete</button>" id="anchor_1464586442243" data-original-title="" title="">Section</highlight> 1 removable true
</p>
```

How to do it? I tried using `.contents().unwrap()` like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4232971/1577357) but it didn't work for me.

This is my current result after using `.contents().unwrap()`:

```
<p><highlight class="highlight" data-id="1464586442243" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<p>first</p><button class=&quot;btn edit_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586442243&quot;>Edit</button>&amp;nbsp;<button class=&quot;btn delete_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586442243&quot;>Delete</button>" id="anchor_1464586442243" data-original-title="" title="">Section</highlight> 1 remov<highlight></highlight>able true</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that by using the jQuery `:contains` selector.

Then select the HTML of the element, insert it before it, and the `remove()` the element.

```
$(function() {
  $('#remove').click(function() {
    $('highlight:contains("removable")').each(function() {
      $(this).before( $(this).html() ).remove();
      // i stuck here
    })
  });
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4qafpgph/2/)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for `$(this).before( $(this).html() ).remove();` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think `replaceWith` method of **jQuery** should help you doing this. Here is working example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#remove').click(function() {
    // Find all the HIGHLIGHT tags which has text "removable"
    var $target = $("highlight:contains('removable')");

    // Replace all those instances of HIGHLIGHT tags with the text inside of each of those
    $target.replaceWith(function(){
     return $(this).text();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <highlight class="highlight" data-id="1464586442243" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<p>first</p><button class=&quot;btn edit_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586442243&quot;>Edit</button>&amp;nbsp;<button class=&quot;btn delete_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586442243&quot;>Delete</button>"
  id="anchor_1464586442243" data-original-title="" title="">Section</highlight> 1
  <highlight class="highlight" data-id="1464586450092" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<p>second</p><button class=&quot;btn edit_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586450092&quot;>Edit</button>&amp;nbsp;<button class=&quot;btn delete_annotation&quot; data-id=&quot;1464586450092&quot;>Delete</button>"
  id="anchor_1464586450092" data-original-title="" title="">removable</highlight> true</p>
<button id="remove" type="button">Remove</button>
```

Happy Coding...

Comment: Thank you for your help Ashish. I really appreciate it. I'm using @LinkinTED answer for now. :)

Comment: No problem mate. But I thought my code also can do what you want. All you needed is to replace the `HIGHLIGHT` element by text inside it, right? :)