# Remove parent two div while child will remain same

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a requirement in which i have to replace this html code to new html code

**Current Html**`

```
<td class="dataCol  first "><div class="requiredInput">
 <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
<select id="pageLeadNew:frmLeadNew:pbLeadNew:pbsCorporateAccounts:IdCompanyTyp" name="pageLeadNew:frmLeadNew:pbLeadNew:pbsCorporateAccounts:IdCompanyTyp" onchange="FuntomangeCorpSection();"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Sub National">Sub National</option>
<option value="Regional Account">Regional Account</option>
<option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
<option value="Embassy">Embassy</option>
<option value="Fleet Operator">Fleet Operator</option>
<option value="Association">Association</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</select></div></td>
```

`

**Required Html**`

```
<td class="dataCol  first ">
<select id="pageLeadNew:frmLeadNew:pbLeadNew:pbsCorporateAccounts:IdCompanyTyp" name="pageLeadNew:frmLeadNew:pbLeadNew:pbsCorporateAccounts:IdCompanyTyp" onchange="FuntomangeCorpSection();"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Sub National">Sub National</option>
<option value="Regional Account">Regional Account</option>
<option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
<option value="Embassy">Embassy</option>
<option value="Fleet Operator">Fleet Operator</option>
<option value="Association">Association</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</select></td>`
```

i have to remove current Html code with required html code in which i have to remove to div with class name ***requiredInput*** and ***requiredBlock***

please help thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a HTML tag but keep the innerHtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232961/remove-a-html-tag-but-keep-the-innerhtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) is what you need, removes the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

```
$('.requiredInput').contents().unwrap();
$('.requiredBlock').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery

```
var datacol = $('td.dataCol.first');
datacol.find('div.requiredBlock').remove();
datacol.find('div.requiredInput').contents().unwrap();
```